# Vlan 20 & native vlan 20

Tags: vlan, switching

If native VLAN 20 wants to communicate with VLAN 20 through a trunk link what happens?
Will native VLAN be able to communicate with VLAN 20?

Answer (score 4):

The "native" VLAN is simply the untagged VLAN on a trunk where VLAN membership is implied. Accordingly, there's no difference between the native VLAN x on a trunk and VLAN x elsewhere.

Whether or not a device also accepts tagged frames with the same VLAN ID that is configured as that interface's native VLAN depends on its implementation.